# How can I call a class from command line using package.class method when I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, class, command-line, program-entry-point

I am required to call a method called query1 from the command line using `java ser322.JdbcLab <url> <user> <pwd> <driver> query1`. However, when I call the method, I get an error: Error: Could not find or load main class ser322.JdbcLab
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ser322.JdbcLab

The project file structure is the attached JdbcLab/src/main/java/ser322/JdbcLab.java. JdbcLab is in package ser322.

I tried using the command from each folder starting with the root folder and ending with the package folder. I read other posts with the same issue and I do not have any typos. I tried using .java and .class. I am using IntelliJ. The file compiles correctly. I am able to go to the package folder and use the command java JdbcLab.java     query1. But I am required to use ser322.JdbcLab command instead.

Comment: In which directory is the *class* file? btw, you can't 'call methods' from the command line. You can only start applications

Comment: *you can't 'call methods' from the command line.* (in normal circumstances)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set up your classpath variable that should solve the problem.

Link for the same

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-classpath-in-java/amp/